# Zimbra SOAP API authenticate using zm_auth_token in java

Tags: java, zimbra

I want to authenticate a user using the zm_auth_token that I dispose :

For the moment, I'm doing this :

```
    LmcAuthRequest auth = new LmcAuthRequest();
    auth.setUsername(userName);
    auth.setPassword(password);
    LmcAuthResponse authResp = (LmcAuthResponse) auth.invoke(serverURL);
    LmcSession session = authResp.getSession();
```

But I want to use the zm_auth_token that I have. How to do this ???
Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zimbra Lmc methods are deprecated now ...
If you want to use SOAP they prefer doing it using ZMailBox (It doesn't work for me), I used this method :

```
// Create the connection where we're going to send the file.
        URL url = new URL(SOAPUrl);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;

        String  postContent = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">"+
        "<soap:Header>" +
        "<context xmlns=\"urn:zimbra\">" +
        "<format type=\"js\"/>" +
        "<authToken>" + authToken + "</authToken>" +
        "</context>" +
        "</soap:Header>" +
        "<soap:Body>" + 
        "<GetFolderRequest xmlns=\"urn:zimbraMail\" />" +
        "</soap:Body>" +
        "</soap:Envelope>";

        // insert your SOAP XML!!!
        byte[] b = postContent.getBytes();

        // Set the appropriate HTTP parameters.
        httpConn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", String.valueOf( b.length ) );
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");
        httpConn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);

        // Everything's set up; send the XML that was read in to b.
        OutputStream out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        out.write( b );
        out.close();

        // Read the response and write it to standard out.
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        // read & do something with input stream...
        String s = null;
        String response = "";
        while((s=in.readLine()) != null){
            response += s;
        }
        in.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SOAPConnectionFactory soapfactory=SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection soapconnection=soapfactory.createConnection();
MessageFactory messagefactory=MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage messege=messagefactory.createMessage();
SOAPEnvelope envelop=messege.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
SOAPHeader header=messege.getSOAPHeader();
SOAPBody body=messege.getSOAPBody();
Name header_context=envelop.createName("context", null,"urn:zimbra");
Name auth_request=envelop.createName("AuthRequest",null,"urn:zimbraAccount");
Name account=envelop.createName("account");
Name password=envelop.createName("password");
header.addHeaderElement(header_context);
SOAPBodyElement auth_body=body.addBodyElement(auth_request);
        auth_body.addChildElement(account).addAttribute(envelop.createName("by"),"name").addTextNode("abc");//(abc==your username)
auth_body.addChildElement(password).addTextNode("1234");//(1234=your password)
URL url=new URL("http://192.168.1.67/service/soap/AuthRequest");
SOAPMessage response=soapconnection.call(messege, url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zimbra libraries for calling SOAP API. Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64230719/4458403).